# Disk Management label disk (not partition)?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, disk-management

I know how to label a partition. I am not asking for that.

Disk Management displays all disks in "Disk #" and its capacity. I have to admit I once had formatted a wrong disk with the same capacity and lost all data on it. So, I would like to prevent any chance like that.

Disks have unique ID and Windows seems to know about it. Is there any way to assign a unique name to a disk other than "Disk #", so that I would not mistake two disks with the same capacity?

If there is no such way, is there any way to display HDD hardware name as a column or below the label, not right-clicking and open property?

Comment: Safest would be to just pull the plug on the other drives. I have the same issue on machines here, with 4 identical drives. Never got the wrong one yet, that way. I mark the drives with a sharpie too, as they go in the machine, so I know which is which.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to rename the physical Disk #. The best way, as you said, would be to check the Hardware properties. I couldn't find any setting or way to customize the columns in Disk Management. There are three different views: Disk List, Volume List, and Graphical View, but none of these show hardware names.

I would suggest labeling the volumes on the disks with more distinct or meaningful names so you are sure which one you are formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but neither the MBR nor the GPT partitioning format support a "disk name". GPT does have a GUID for the entire disk, but not a human-readable name. So it's not just a question of no tools or UI available to do this; there is just no provision on the disk for it, at all.